How do I create an SQL (not Windows) login without a password for use with EXECUTE AS?
I want to create a login on SQL Server. I do not want it to use Windows authentication. In fact, I want it to use no authentication at all. I want to have a high-privileged user which will be used to run a server-level trigger using the EXECUTE AS clause of CREATE TRIGGER. However, the only way to create a non-Windows SQL login seems to require me to specify a password or hash.
Is there a recommended way to do this? Should I generate a random password? Can I supply an invalid hash which will never be matched by any password?

Looks very related to your use case https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/335883/3690

@MartinSmith I don’t really see how specifying a certificate credential is fundamentally different from using a random password. Yes, it should be much harder to create an insecure certificate than an insecure password. I am being convinced more than ever that an SQL login which is disabled is as close as one can get to a passwordless user—it’s not the same as a passwordless user in Linux, instead it’s like a password-locked user.

I would be curious to know why you need your trigger to "execute as" ...
Maybe if you describe what you are trying to do and how, someone could come with a better approch.

@DominiqueBoucher I need EXECUTE AS so that my trigger can execute commands which require permissions which the logins accessing the server and triggering the trigger don’t and shouldn’t have. That’s, like, one of the obvious use cases for EXECUTE AS.

Are those objet in the same database ? I did a quick test creating a table in which the trigger will write (test). I then created a fake login that only has acces to modify 1 table (user). I tried and that user cannot read nor write in the "test" table. After updating a row in the user table, the trigger ran and wrote into the test table.
You could also run it as "sa" I guess...

@DominiqueBoucher It’s a server-level trigger, so not related to databases.

Yes, sa might be an option but I’d rather not assume it exists.

Instead of working with password you can create a Login based on a certificate.
And the certificate can be encrypted by the database master key, not with a password either.
Like so:
CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'The password that is used to encrypt the master key in the database. password must meet the Windows password policy requirements of the computer that is running the instance of SQL Server.'

GO
CREATE CERTIFICATE CertForLogin   
WITH SUBJECT = 'For Trigger'  
,   EXPIRY_DATE = '20991031';  

GO
CREATE LOGIN [LoginFromCert] FROM CERTIFICATE CertForLogin

GO

It looks like for my use case, the an option is to create a login with a blank password and disable it. This can be done in a transaction to prevent anyone from using the account before it is disabled.
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
CREATE LOGIN myLogin WITH PASSWORD = N'', CHECK_EXPIRATION = OFF, CHECK_POLICY = OFF;
ALTER LOGIN myLogin DISABLE;
COMMIT;

I am not convinced of this approach. Now that this user exists, it wouldn’t be that hard to create a large security hole by simply enabling the user later.

What advantage is the blank password giving you over a long randomly generated one?

@MartinSmith There are two things. I want a simple script/pattern. Adding randomly generated passwords makes this more complicated; I suddenly need to worry about the quality of the entropy and whatnot and calculate the right password length and schedule a periodic audit of this code if I want to worry about security or something. The other issue is that writing code which uses a randomly generated password makes it look like the randomly generated password is meant to provide security when I really just want a login which is entirely incompatible with password authentication.

OK - but now you are worrying about the possibility of it being enabled and opening a massive security hole. I think you are over thinking the entropy. You can just use CONVERT(VARCHAR(128),CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(64),2) and get on with your day. You don't even need to record it anywhere as no one will be using it. This is in addition to the login being disabled not instead of it.
